# Should I use: FogBuz + Beanstalk OR Assembla

Tags: svn, project-management, bug-tracking

I am in the processes of setting up a 4 to 6 person development team (3 countries). Basically what I need is a subversion scm to integrate with visual studio and a project management (tasks, wiki etc) web tool.

- Are there any pros and cons about using "FogBuz + Beanstalk" OR just use "Assembla" for my source code and project management?
- Any other site suggestions are welcome.

P/S: I hope this is not too subjective. I just need a unordered list of cons/pro.

[Edit]

- We use **GMail**, so *GMail Integration* will be a plus.
- Security, ie.e limiting a developer only to their projects or project module is also a plus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I recommend unfuddle. We chose it over both beanstalk and assembla.

Comment: I've used unfuddle as well, an liked it.

Comment: It apparently has Gmail integration, at least with OpenID, if that's what you mean, Tawani. But I haven't used that, so I can't tell you if it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use Assembla, you will end with less users accounts.

unfuddle, basecamp or jira does not have enough features to pay for or are too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Basecamp](http://www.basecamphq.com/) and [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/), I'm extremely happy with both.

Answer (score 0):

I use FogBugz, and 7.0 is a great upgrade. It has a new plugin architecture (see podcast #62) which means that any integration that hasn't already been coded can be, if necessary.

It also fits into my workflow very well, and its "Evidence Based Scheduling" feature's quite cool, and I'd imagine it'd be useful for a bigger team.

Also, you don't want to show the other answers to [Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky). ;)